# Is there a way to attach a "memo" to an ERC-20 `approve` transaction

Tags: solidity, web3js, erc-20, metamask

I know that an ERC-20 `approve` method has only 2 parameters: `sender` and `amount`.
I'd like to get an extra hash recorded on chain with the approval, so I can test it later when coming to process `transferFrom` requests.

Ideally, my flow would be: user reads description on page, telling them they're about to approve n tokens for purpose X. When they click a button, MetaMask pops up, and shows them a message saying "you're approving n of token t with data X". Later on, I can find the approval transaction, and get "X" from it.

Is there a way to include extra information with the transaction - without writing an external smart contract?

Answer (score 2):

You can use ethers to encode the `transfer` or `approve` function's data then append your memo to that data.

The data will be more than the transfer function needs but luckily `EVM` will ignore the extra data kinda the point of why all function arguments are zero-padded.

Keep in mind you have to encode data your self and also decode the data your self from the other side.

Here is a quick example

```js
import ethers from "ethers"

// Example ERC-20 contract address and ABI (replace with your actual contract details)
const contractAddress = '0xYourContractAddress';
const contractAbi = [...];  // Replace with your ERC-20 ABI

const provider =  {} // replace with your provider
const signer = {} // replace with your signer

// Your ERC-20 contract instance
const contract = new ethers.Contract(contractAddress, contractAbi, provider);

// Recipient address and amount to transfer
const toAddress = '0xRecipientAddress';
const amount = 100n; // replace with the amount you want to transfer

const data = contract.interface.encodeFunctionData('transfer', [toAddress, amount]);

const memo = ethers.hexlify(ethers.toUtf8Bytes("Hello memo"));

const transaction = {
  to: await token.getAddress(),
  // we need to slice the memo to remove 0x before appending
  data: data + memo.slice(2),
};

const tx = await signer.sendTransaction(transaction);

// somewhere else you can get the transaction 
const tx = provider.getTransaction(txHash)

// 0x + function selector 4bytes-8chars + 2 32bytes arguments = 138 
const hexMemo = tx.data.substring(138, tx.data.length);

const memoString = ethers.toUtf8String("0x" + txMemo1);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can usually add data to any transaction, so you can add some message converted to bytes to send a message onchain.

Look into [this](https://dame.mirror.xyz/5xbwbVzWcO8vQkEIGlMaUjXNM6UNM8labiN-5QkVCHM)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but this shows how to add data to a blockchain in a transaction - but I need it to be part of an ERC-20 `approve` transaction.

Comment: As you said, approve only takes 2 args, so you can't add a message in the arguments. But you can add extra data to your approve call (i.e. your message like shown in the link I shared), so that would be part of the approve transaction

Comment: How exactly? The link you specified shows how to create a tx that contains a hash manually, using MyEtherWallet, I need code that does it with an actual approve tx.